# Windows Server 2008 R2 Changing Editions post installation

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to switch from Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition to Web Edition without reinstalling?

Answer (score 4):

No.............

Answer (score 0):

No. The only edition changes that are possible are Standard -> Enterprise -> DataCenter. Nothing can go to or from Web edition or Hyper-V Server. You also can not switch full to/from core.